# How to save UIView into camera roll without displaying view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I want to implement simple sharing function. In my app if user long pressed on `UITableViewCell`, it's present `UIActionController` with some buttons.
The first one allows to share content with friends (`UIActivityViewController`)

My goal is to save cell text with brand watermark in the right corner.

For now, I'm using this extension for converting `UIView` to `UImage`:

```
extension UIView {
    func convertToImage() -> UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
            self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return UIImage(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
        }
    }
}
```

But I have some problems with it. It's works only when the view presented on screen. If I try to get an image from `UIView` which is not shown on the screen, I get an empty variable.

Even with vc:

```
let vc = ViewController()
let image = vc.view.convertToImage()
//Image empty
```

I don't want that user see content with watermark on the screen, I need watermark be added only to the camera roll.

**Can I do it?**

Comment: You're close. Consider: Contexts aren't necessarily visible. If you can place everything into a UIView that is hidden, capture it. (I've done this so I know it works.)

Comment: I tried to use isHidden, but I just get a white image without text and watermark.

Comment: Kkk just don’t add the view that you need to render to the content view. If you hide it what do you expect to render?

Comment: I'd honestly expect a black view - no view - but could be wrong. Transfer your view (whatever it is, image, text, , simple view, hierarchical) **in** the new context. Add your watermark. aarendeo it and get your "snapshot". what is visible to the user, is. What you do in this **new** context isn't unless you make it.